# SQLite select all records and count

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (my_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING, number STRING);
```

Running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

Produces the following output:

```
1|someone|111
2|someone|222
3|monster|333
```

Along with these three fields I would also like to include a count representing the amount of times the same name exists in the table.

I've obviously tried:

```
SELECT my_id, name, count(name) FROM sometable GROUP BY name;
```

though that will not give me an individual result row for every record.

Ideally I would have the following output:

```
1|someone|111|2
2|someone|222|2
3|monster|333|1
```

Where the 4th column represents the amount of time this number exists.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have to use subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `select` clause:

```
Select st.*,
       (SELECT count(*) from sometable st2 where st.name = st2.name) as NameCount
from sometable st;
```

You can also write this as a `join` to an aggregated subquery:

```
select st.*, stn.NameCount
from sometable st join
     (select name, count(*) as NameCount
      from sometable
      group by name
    ) stn
    on st.name = stn.name;
```

EDIT:

As for performance, the best way to find out is to try both and time them.  The correlated subquery will work best when there is an index on `sometable(name)`.  Although aggregation is reputed to be slow in MySQL, sometimes this type of query gets surprisingly good results.  The best answer is to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *, (SELECT count(my_id) from sometable) as total from sometable
```